# How to verify data migration from a sequence of rows? Case statement attempted/failed

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I am trying to verify the success of a data migration to two new columns. Our developers created a script to populate the tables and I need to verify with a query.

The two tables are:

**dbo.req** (the ncv columns are new)

- req_id
- ncv1
- ncv2

**dbo.req_map**

- req_id
- nach_id
- seq

My instructions are as follows:

- for each req_id in dbo.req, find all matching rows in dbo.req_map
- traverse all matching rows, starting with the lowest seq value, ascending
- insert the first "nach_id" value into dbo.req.ncv1 column
- traverse the remaining rows, if another unique "nach_id" value is found, insert it into ncv2 column
- then stop processing this req_id

Example data below. I can manage the first half of the query, but can't figure out how to traverse for the ncv2 column. My query thus far:

```
SELECT
cr.req_id,
cr.ncv1,
cr.ncv2,
ccm.nach_id,
ccm.seq,
CASE WHEN ccm.nach_id = cr.ncv1 OR ccm.nach_id = 0 AND cr.ncv2 = null
then 'OK' else ':('
end as "Match?"
FROM dbo.req cr
LEFT JOIN dbo.req_map ccm
ON cr.req_id = ccm.req_id
```

Example data below:

dbo.req

| req_id | ncv1 | ncv2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23227 | 100 | 1541 |
| 25000 | 100 | 1541 |

dbo.req_map

| req_id | nach_id | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23227 | 100 | 0 |
| 23227 | 100 | 1 |
| 23227 | 1541 | 2 |
| 23227 | 100 | 3 |
| 23227 | 100 | 4 |
| 23227 | 100 | 5 |
| 23227 | 100 | 6 |
| 23227 | 100 | 7 |
| 23227 | 0 | 8 |
| 23227 | 0 | 9 |
| 23227 | 100 | 10 |
| 23227 | 100 | 11 |
| 23227 | 100 | 12 |
| 23227 | 0 | 13 |
| 23227 | 0 | 14 |
| 23227 | 0 | 15 |
| 23227 | 100 | 16 |
| 23227 | 100 | 17 |
| 23227 | 100 | 18 |
| 23227 | 0 | 19 |
| 23227 | 100 | 20 |
| 23227 | 0 | 21 |
| 23227 | 1541 | 22 |
| 23227 | 1541 | 23 |
| 25000 | 100 | 0 |
| 25000 | 100 | 1 |
| 25000 | 1541 | 2 |
| 25000 | 100 | 3 |
| 25000 | 100 | 4 |
| 25000 | 100 | 5 |
| 25000 | 100 | 6 |
| 25000 | 100 | 7 |
| 25000 | 100 | 8 |
| 25000 | 100 | 9 |
| 25000 | 100 | 10 |
| 25000 | 100 | 11 |
| 25000 | 100 | 12 |
| 25000 | 100 | 13 |
| 25000 | 0 | 14 |
| 25000 | 0 | 15 |
| 25000 | 100 | 16 |
| 25000 | 100 | 17 |
| 25000 | 100 | 18 |
| 25000 | 0 | 19 |
| 25000 | 100 | 20 |
| 25000 | 0 | 21 |
| 25000 | 1541 | 22 |
| 25000 | 1541 | 23 |

Comment: Are you sure you want `ccm.nach_id = cr.ncv1 OR (ccm.nach_id = 0 AND cr.ncv2 = null)`?

Comment: Start with doing `cr.ncv2 IS null` .

Comment: The nach_id is the value I want to populate the new columns nvc1 and ncv2. The first sequence of nach_id will be ncv1 and the next unique value in the following sequences will be ncv2.